# ConnectSsl method throws System.IO.IOException. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, ioexception, socketexception

I have tests that daily check a gmail folder for new emails. This has been working for over a year, and suddenly recently started failing when calling Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port). I'm using Assembly ActiveUp.Net.Imap4, Version=5.0.3454.364

```
private Imap4Client client;

        public MailRepository(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
        {
            if (ssl)
                Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
            else
                Client.Connect(mailServer, port);
            Client.Login(login, password);
        }
```

Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
'Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port)' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146232800
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"}
    Message: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
    Source: "System"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ValidateCreateContext(Boolean isServer, String targetHost, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, X509Certificate serverCertificate, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, Boolean remoteCertRequired, Boolean checkCertRevocationStatus, Boolean checkCertName)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)\r\n   at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Imap4Client.DoSslHandShake(SslHandShake sslHandShake)\r\n   at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Imap4Client.ConnectSsl(String host, Int32 port, SslHandShake sslHandShake)\r\n   at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Imap4Client.ConnectSsl(String host, Int32 port)"
    TargetSite: {Void ValidateCreateContext(Boolean, System.String, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)}

Researching further I was recommended to see if Firewall may be blocking it, and it's not. Looking for options. Thanks